# trying to ALTER a table based on the results from a SELECT statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, datediff, alter

when i use the following select statement i can return the date differences between date_due and date_returned.

```
select Date_Due,Date_Returned,
datediff(Date_Due,Date_Returned) as Day_Diff 
From tp_rental
```

However i cant get these values to replace the current null values in the tp_rental table. I tried the below statement also thinking it would create a new column.

```
alter table tp_rental
ADD DayDiff as DATEDIFF (Date_Due,Date_Returned);
```

my errors say there is a problem with the syntax near as DATEDIFF

any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generated column expressions need to be enclosed in `()` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)). You also need to add a column type definition:

```
alter table tp_rental
ADD DayDiff INT as (DATEDIFF(Date_Due,Date_Returned));
```

Comment: Hi Nick, unfortunately thats not working for me, i get the same error saying error for the right syntax to use near as (DateDiff....

Comment: @Gary sorry - didn't notice the missing column type, See my edit